Conjugate observables - can the commutation relations be generalised?
Conjugate variables are variables that are Fourier transforms of one another (that is they are Fourier transform duals) and consequently have an uncertainty relation existing between them. In quantum mechanics, two self-adjoint operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ defined on the same Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ are said to be canonically conjugate if they satisfy the commutation relations
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A}, \hat{B}] =  \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A} = \mathrm{i}\hat{I},~~~(1)
\end{equation}
where $\hat{I}$ is the identity operator on $\mathcal{H}$ (the right-hand-side of this is sometimes multiplied by a factor of $\hbar$ to render this expression in dimensions of action). My question is whether this is, in fact, the most general form that encapsulates the essence of such observables being conjugate to one another. Specifically, could one assert the more general relation
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A}, \hat{B}] =  \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A} = \mathrm{i}\hat{C},~~~(2)
\end{equation}
where $\hat{C}$ is an arbitrary invertible Hermitian operator. Is there some reason why this expression cannot be used as a generalisation of (1)?
My thoughts on this are that when the first condition (1) applies, the fact that $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are Fourier duals somehow implies that commutator must be proportional to the identity operator, rather than a general Hermitian operator as suggested in (2). However, I have been unable to demonstrate this. Initial thoughts are that one might try constructing $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ via
\begin{equation}
\hat{A} \equiv  \sum_{i} \left|A_{i}\right>A_{i}\left<A_{i}\right|
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\hat{B} \equiv  \sum_{j} \left|B_{j}\right>B_{j}\left<B_{j}\right|
\end{equation}
(or in terms of integrals for continuous variables) where $A_{i}$ and $B_{j}$ are the eigenvalues of $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ respectively and then try to show that the matrix
\begin{equation}
-\mathrm{i}[\hat{A}, \hat{B}] =  -\mathrm{i}\sum_{i,j} \left(\left|A_{i}\right>A_{i}\left<A_{i}|B_{j}\right>B_{j}\left<B_{j}\right| - \left|B_{j}\right>B_{j}\left<B_{j}|A_{i}\right>A_{i}\left<A_{i}\right|\right)
\end{equation}
is proportional to the identity operator. However, I have not been able to do this and I am not entirely sure how to impose the condition that $A_{i}$ and $B_{j}$ should be Fourier duals, other than the fact that the kets $\left|A_{i}\right>$ and $\left|B_{j}\right>$ are not orthonormal to one another. Is there a way of showing that this requires the form of (1) and that (2) does not, in general, apply?
Edit.
It would seem that many people are not understanding my question. The concept of canonically conjugate variables is described in this Wiki article. To quote:

In quantum mechanics, the canonical commutation relation is the fundamental relation between canonical conjugate quantities (quantities which are related by definition such that one is the Fourier transform of another). For example,
\begin{equation}
[\hat{x}, \hat{p}_{x}] = i\hat{I},
\end{equation}
between the position operator x and momentum operator $p_x$ in the $x$ direction of a point particle in one dimension, where $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}_{x}] = \hat{x}\hat{p}_{x}-\hat{p}_{x}\hat{x}$ is the commutator of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}_{x}$, $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant $h/2\pi$, and $\hat{I}$ is the unit operator.

My question is why do conjugate variables require this particular form? Specifically, can one derive this form from the requirement of being Fourier duals? How does one do this?
Secondly, is it possible to assert a more general relation that would encapsulate a conjugate relation between the observables? Specifically, Equation (2) above. If not, why not?
Further edit.
I have reworded my question somewhat as I am interested in the physical properties of conjugate relations between observables and how one might formulate this mathematically, not the historical definition of the term 'canonically conjugate'. I think this has been a source of confusion, which I realise is my own fault - I was using the term 'canonically conjugate' when I really just meant 'conjugate'.

I am not sure to understand well the issue. Howevr condition (2) is "empty"!
Given a pair of Hermitian operators A,B
, we can define
C:=−i[A,B]
and (2) would be automatically satisfied. Notice that C
is Hermitian as well on its natural domain. At most C
could not to be invertible, but adding this condition would be too weak to select relevant physics.

I don't understand the question. What do you mean with "canonically conjugated" except eq. 1? If this is your definition, then $A,B$ in eq. 2 are c.c. iff $C=I$. Can you elaborate? With "Fourier duals", you mean that both operators transform into each other when transforming them with the unitary Fourier-Plancherel operator? Anyway, even $(1)$ don't imply this, I think, because $(1)$ in general has no unique solution.  Take e.g. $A=X$, $B=P+f(X)$. Then $A,B$ are not related via Fourier transform.

Are you familiar with  angular momentum?

I don't understand some of the more "visceral" reactions to the question. I am not sure I understand the question, either, though. Is it about the meaning of the word "canonical"? Is it a  general question about "physical" operator algebras? The first one sounds more like history of science to me, while the second one seems to have some beef to it. I would certainly like to hear more about Valter Moretti's angle with regards to "strong enough to select relevant physics". That sounds like something we should want to understand. @ValterMoretti

I too would like to hear a little more elaboration on @ValterMoretti's comments.

The notion of conjugate variables comes all the way from classical mechanics. There one defined a "conjugate momentum" from the derivative of the Lagrangian. Enter quantum physics and we get Planck's relation and de Broglie's relation. The latter links the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$ to the momentum. While momentum and position are conjugate variables ala classical mechanics, the wave vector and the position are Fourier variables. So quantum physics is responsible for introducing Fourier theory into the mix. As it turns out, the properties of the operators that we are familiar with in quantum mechanics are more a consequence of the mathematical properties of the Fourier transform than of quantum physics per se.
So, one can just take Fourier theory and introduce an operator formalism into it. Define two sets of coordinate bases (for the one-dimensional case) $|x\rangle$ and $|k\rangle$ for the position and Fourier domain, respectively. We assume that they are orthogonal bases so that $\langle x|x'\rangle=\delta(x-x')$ and $\langle k|k'\rangle=2\pi\delta(k-k')$. They are also complete, which means that
$$ \int |x\rangle \langle x|\ dx = \mathbf{1} = \int |k\rangle \langle k|\ \frac{dk}{2\pi} , $$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity operator. Since these two bases are associated with domains that are related by Fourier transforms, they are mutually unbiased, which means that $\langle x|k\rangle=\exp(ixk)$. Then we can define operators for the expectation values in the two domain. They are
$$ \hat{x} = \int |x\rangle x \langle x|\ dx ~~~ \text{and} ~~~
\hat{k} = \int |k\rangle k \langle k|\ \frac{dk}{2\pi} . $$
They can be interpreted as the position and "momentum" operators. They can also be expressed in terms of the opposite bases with the aid of derivatives. To do this, we overlap one operator by identities resolved in terms of the other basis. For example
$$ \mathbf{1}\hat{k}\mathbf{1} 
= \int |x\rangle \langle x|k\rangle k \langle k|x'\rangle \langle x'|\ \frac{dk\ dx\ dx'}{2\pi} . $$
It becomes
$$ \hat{k} 
= \int |x\rangle k\exp[i(x-x')k] \langle x'| \frac{dk dx dx'}{2\pi} = \int |x\rangle (-i\partial_x)\exp[i(x-x')k] \langle x'| \frac{dk dx dx'}{2\pi} . $$
Finally, we have
$$ \hat{k} = \int |x\rangle (-i\partial_x)\delta(x-x') \langle x'|\ dx\ dx'
= \int |x\rangle (-i\partial_x) \langle x|\ dx . $$
So, if you now take both operators in the same basis, one having to be defined as a derivative, then a simple exercise shows that they commute:
$$ [\hat{x},\hat{k}] = i . $$
The sum and difference of these operators (with appropriate constants to ensure that the dimensions match) can then be used as ladder operators, from which follows the definition of the Fock basis etc.; all this without actually introducing any quantum physics.
In general one can have lots of different Hermitian operators that would in general not commute with one another. However, unless their basis are mutually unbiased [which basically implies that $\langle a|b\rangle = \exp(iab)$], they would not produce the same form of commutation relation, and therefore not qualify as being canonical.

This goes much closer to the heart of my question. The part I am interesting in is how one goes from your formal definition of the operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{k}$ to the expression of one in the basis of the other using derivatives. Can you show explicitly how to do this? I know what the result should be and that $[\hat{x},\hat{k}]=i$ follows from it. Its the proof of how it is done I am after.

Just to be clear, how would one show that, for example, $\hat{k} = -i\int\left|x\right>\partial/\partial x\left<x\right|dx$? (Here $\partial/\partial x$ operates on whatever $\left<x\right|$ projects onto - I realise the formal expression looks mathematically spurious).

@MartinVaughan You cannot do this with only the "definitions" given in the post. You need further information, say e.g. the overlap $\langle x|k\rangle$. To be clear: The equations $\hat x=\ldots$ and $\hat k=\ldots$ are only at a formal level; they tell you that they consider two hermitian operators with continuous spectrum (roughly speaking, and mathematically everything needs more work).

@TobiasFunke So how does one actually go from flippiefanus's constructions for $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{k}$ to the relation $[\hat{x},\hat{k}] = i$? Are you saying that this does not actually follow and that one, in fact, needs more information? For instance, does one need to assume the form of the $\left<x|k\right>$ first?

@MartinVaughan I am saying that these two equations alone don't mean anything a priori. What I mean is that the equations are supposed to mean (presumably) "we have two hermitian operators with continuous spectrum (equal to the whole real line) and eigenstates "orthonormalized" with Dirac deltas". Then if you are given the overlap, you can conclude also the commutator. Ofc., in practice you are given first the explicit relations of the operators (say, as multiplication and derivative), then derive the commutation and overlap; at least this is to my experience what is done in textbooks.

See the edits. I added the definition of the bases and show the derivation of $\hat{k}$ as an operator. @TobiasFünke "these two equations alone don't mean anything a priori." That is the whole point. It is just formalism and not physics. The only requirement at this point is that the math must be consistent.

I am not sure to understand well the issue.
Conjugate variables are defined in the usual way and this is nothing but a definition, useful for many proposals and arising from classical Hamiltonian mechanics. There is not much to say about a definition.
What we can discuss is whether or not there are physically meaningful  generalizations of that definition.
Given a pair of Hermitian operators $A,B$, we can define $$C:= -i[A,B]$$ and (2) would be automatically satisfied.
Notice that $C$  is Hermitian as well on its natural domain. At most $C$ could not to be invertible, but even adding this condition would be too weak to select relevant physics.
A minimal requirement which extends the standard notion of conjugate variables is that $-iA,-iB$, and $-iC$, defined as above, are the generators of a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of dimension $d\leq 3$. This is equivalent to saying that the commutators $[A,C]$ and $[B,C]$ are imaginary linear combinations of $A,B,C$.
Under some further technical hypotheses (for instance that $A^2+B^2+C^2$ is essentially selfadjoint on a dense domain $D$ invariant under $A,B,C$), there is a (unique) unitary (strongly continuous) representation, in the Hilbert space of the considered physical system, of the unique (simply connected) Lie group $G$ whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$.
The generators of the one-parameter groups of $G$ are all real linear combinations of $A,B,C$ (more precisely their closures on $D$).
According to Wigner's ideas, this group is a simmetry group of the physical system.
Here physics enters the play in terms of symmetries.
Elementary examples are the very standard commutation relations, where $A=X$, $B=P$, $C=I$. In this case $G$ is the 3D Heisenberg group.
Another standard  case is made of the three generators of the angular momentum. In that case $G=SU(2)$ (physically speaking  $SO(3)$).
The most elementary case is perhaps given by the abelian group of the spatial translations, of a particle confined in a plane  whose generators $A$ and $B$ are the momentum operators along $x$ and $y$ and $C=0$.
To conclude, I also observe that, if a one parameter group has the meaning of time evolution (i.e., its generator is the Hamiltonian of the system), then the generators are constants of motion. Their one parameter groups are continuous dynamical symmetries.


\begin{equation}
[\hat{A}, \hat{B}] =  \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A} = \mathrm{i}\hat{I},~~~(1)
\end{equation}
...
\begin{equation}
[\hat{A}, \hat{B}] =  \hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A} = \mathrm{i}\hat{C},~~~(2)
\end{equation}


Is there some reason why this more general expression cannot be used to define the condition of being canonical conjugate?

Yes, there is a reason. You don't get to unilaterally and arbitrarily modify long-standing definitions. (Or, you can, but don't be surprised when no one knows what you are talking about.)
The definition of the canonical commutation relationship between what we call "position" and what we call "momentum" is:
$$
[x,p]=i\hbar
$$
Other operators can have different relationships, there is nothing wrong with that. They just won't be considered position and momentum, from a physical perspective.
For example, creation and annihilation operators satisfy a different commutation relation:
$$
[a,a^\dagger] = 1\;.
$$
For example, angular momentum operators satisfy a different commutation relation:
$$
[J_i,J_j] = i\epsilon_{ijk}\hbar J_k\;.
$$

My question is why do canonically conjugate observables require this particular form?

First, as a matter of convention, the particular form is needed because otherwise the operators will not be understood as canonical position and momentum operators by anyone else in the world. Second, and worse, if you pick some different commutation relationship it may not be a possible way to interpret the operators as the position and momentum.

... is it possible to assert a more general relation that would also satisfy this condition? Specifically, Equation (2) above. If not, why not?

As explained above, you can "assert" whatever you like, but do not expect to be understood if you flout conventions and do not expect that you will be able to describe the physics of position and momentum.

The position operator, acting on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ as a multiplication operator with the identity map, is the Fourier transform of the momentum operator, acting on the same space by differentiation (roughly speaking). In formulas: $UXU^\dagger=P$, where $U$ is the (unitary) Fourier-Plancherel operator. Or did I misunderstood your statement: " Fourier transforms are involved, but the momentum is not the Fourier transform of the position--that doesn't really make sense"?

I took OP's "variables" and "fourier transform" to mean the real numbers $x$ and $p$ in an expression like: $\tilde \phi(p) = \int dx e^{-ipx}\phi(x)$. In this case $x$ and $p$ are not Fourier transforms of each other. I don't know what you mean regarding the Fourier-Plancherel operator and its relation to OP's "fourier transform."

Anyways, I removed the offending paragraph
